# Why does "process.stdin.read" read fire when there is a `readable` handler?

Tags: node.js, stream

When I emit a `stdin` `readable` event, and if I have `process.stdin.read` overwritten to a mock I see the following.

```
process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
  console.log('readable emitted')
  process.stdin.read()
})
process.stdin.read = (...args) => console.log({msg: 'read fired', args})
process.stdin.emit('readable')
```

logs:

```
readable emitted
{ msg: 'read fired', args: [] }
{ msg: 'read fired', args: [ 0 ] }
```

I am trying to get this mock to work, however, it won't work if there are extra calls or I am not responding to this initial call correctly.

```
const mockStdinRead = (message) => {
  const gen = function * () {
    yield message
  }
  const it = gen()
  const callerFn = (bool) => {
    console.log({bool})
    if (bool === 0) return null
    const called = it.next().value
    console.log({called})
    return called || null
  }
  return callerFn
}
```

What is responsible for this second call?

Comment: Just an observation: Calling the original `process.stdin.read()` also emit the `readable` event. [TIO](https://tio.run/##bY/BDoMgDIbvPEVvQuLwvsS9C9rOsCA1QHYxPjsDk2Uad2z7tf3@l3mbOAa7pJtnpJyXwCPFqGNC6zV72QQyaAZHTQtSQf@AVQCM7CM70o6nHwE025QIG1WIroPzrUpJJTYlBDusFfR/ED1Yj/LUV@KKlV2ptTZhirvUUWid43SHXQueNhShFipYX1@0qvMhpPrKFdVTSGRfpjl/AA).